# decreasing sequences on [0,1]

Tags: sequences-and-series

Choose a sequence of values in the interval [0,1] in a random manner. If the value of any sequential choice exceeds that of the previous choice, then the sequence is terminated at that previous value. What is the expected terminal value for such sequences?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I have simulated the problem with a computer program and also have found an argument to the conclusion that the expected terminal point would be 3-e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the fact, that the random experiment is (in a sense) contained in itself, since after choosing the first and second random numbers $X, Y \in [0,1]$ in the case of $Y \leq X$ the experiment is iterated with $Y$ being the new $X$. However, let's be more precise.

In the following, I will denote the outcome of the experiment $Z$ and the first (second) number drawn $X$ ($Y$).

Now, let for every $x \in [0,1]$
$$f(x) = \mathbb{E}[Z|X=x]$$
be the expected outcome of the experiment given that in the beginning the number $x$ was chosen. First of all, it can be shown that $f$ is continuous. Furthermore, it holds
$$ f(x) = \int_0^1 \mathbb{E}[Z|X=x, Y=y] \, dy = \int_0^x f(y) \, dy + x (1-x), $$
since in the case of $Y \leq x$ the expected outcome of the experiment is exactly $f(y)$ and otherwise it is simply $x$ and the latter event has probability $(1-x)$. Using that $f$ is continuous we find that it has a antiderivative $F$ and we obtain
$$ f(x) = F(x) - F(0) + x(1-x). $$
But then we can obtain $F$ as solution of the ode
$$ y' = y + x(1-x). $$
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%3D+y+%2B+x%281-x%29) confirms that the general solution to this ode is
$$ g(x) = Ce^x +x^2 + x + 1, $$
with a free variable $C$. Hence we have (remember that in the above ode $f$ is the derivative not the function)
$$ f(x) = Ce^x + 2x + 1 $$
for some $C$. It is clear that $f(0) = 0$ must hold. Hence it is $C = -1$. A WolframAlpha plot of $f$ can be found [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-e%5Ex%2B2x%2B1+for+x+between+0+and+1).

The expected value of $Z$ is then
$$ \mathbb{E} Z = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 - e^x + 2x + 1 \, dx = 3-e \approx 0.28. $$